# Tracing a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

This is for a simple web UI.  A form that allows the user to create a new marker.  It worked with Validation yesterday, but appears to have stopped today.  It now throws a NullReferenceException at a certain point.  Commenting out the reference moves the exception back in the file.

**Definy bits**

```
const string sDateTimeFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateTime dtStartPeriod = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime dtEndPeriod = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime createDate = DateTime.Now;
string cellNumber1 = null;
string cellNumber2 = null;
string cellNumber3 = null;

if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["vehicleId"], out value))
{
    vehicleId = value;
}
else
{
    vehicleId = -1;
}

Validation.Add("vehicleId",
    Validator.Integer("You must choose a valid vehicle"),
    Validator.Required("You must choose a vehicle from the list"),
    Validator.Range(1000, 9999, "Pick a vehicle from the list provided")
);

Validation.Add("startDate",
    Validator.DateTime(),
    Validator.Required("Start date is a required field"),
    Validator.StringLength(19, 19, "Start date's format is " + sDateTimeFormat + " and is 19 characters long")
);

Validation.Add("endDate",
    Validator.DateTime(),
    Validator.Required("End date is a required field"),
    Validator.StringLength(19, 19, "End date's format is " + sDateTimeFormat + " and is 19 characters long")
);
```

**Html form elements**

```
        <fieldset name="startDateFieldSet">
            <label for="startDateControl">Pick Start Date</label>
            <input type="datetime"
                   name="startDate"
                   id="startDateControl"
                   class="@Validation.ClassFor("startDate")"
                   value="@((dtStartPeriod == DateTime.MinValue) ? "" : dtStartPeriod.ToString(sDateTimeFormat))" /> 

            @Html.ValidationMessage("startDate")
            <br /><span class="requiredFormat">@sDateTimeFormat</span>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset name="endDateFieldSet">
            <label for="endDateControl">Pick End Date</label>
            <input type="datetime"
                   name="endDate"
                   id="endDateControl"
                   class="@Validation.ClassFor("endDate")"
                   value="@((dtEndPeriod == DateTime.MinValue) ? "" : dtEndPeriod.ToString(sDateTimeFormat))" />

            @Html.ValidationMessage("endDate")
            <br /><span class="requiredFormat">@sDateTimeFormat</span>
        </fieldset>
```

**Screenshots**
[screenshot 1 http://www.ctrackonline.com.au/screenshots/anchor-1.jpg](http://www.ctrackonline.com.au/screenshots/anchor-1.jpg)

[screenshot 2 http://www.ctrackonline.com.au/screenshots/anchor-2.jpg](http://www.ctrackonline.com.au/screenshots/anchor-2.jpg)

[screenshot 3 http://www.ctrackonline.com.au/screenshots/anchor-3.jpg](http://www.ctrackonline.com.au/screenshots/anchor-3.jpg)

[screenshot 4 http://www.ctrackonline.com.au/screenshots/anchor-4.jpg](http://www.ctrackonline.com.au/screenshots/anchor-4.jpg)

Comment: It's probably caused by the Hungarian notation!

Comment: I only did that to the date fields to make separation between the c# var from the html var easier while troubleshooting earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it due to your @cellNumber1.ToString?

Comment: I am ashamed.  I thought the problem was above :/

Answer (score 0):

In your Exception settings check off NullReferenceException under the System exceptions. That will cause it to be thrown at the first place it occurs.

You can access the exceptions window from Debug --> Windows --> Exceptions in VS 2015

Comment: You can do the same thing in 2013 as well https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/038tzxdw(v=vs.120).aspx